# Error of non-existent field in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and have some code that I am running.I get an error that says the following in the command window:

```
error of non-existent field 'W'
Error in schedule2control (line 7)
 ui   = vertcat(schedule.control(c).W(:).val);
```

I understand that its telling me the variable W is non-existent. 
If that is the case should that variable not show up under work space??
The variable its telling me is non existent (W) exists in my work space.
Any help/clarification would be great.

Comment: You're not referencing the varaible `W` here, but the field `schedule.control.W`. Check `isfield(schedule.control,'W')` to see if the field `W` exists.

Comment: @Richard thanks for the clarification. You are correct as it returns an answer of 0.